# ASP.NET Identity Concurrent Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application. This application is not something that will be used internally, but rather will get installed on a server and sold to customers who will use it internally.

So with that, we have limited the number of users that can access it (different packages: 10, 25, 50, or unlimited). The problem is, however, that with ASP.NET Identity, concurrent logins are allowed. This means if a customer has a 10-user system, they could all log in as the same user, and have effectively unlimited user access. So if "Dave" logged in as Dave, then Jim could log in as Dave, as could Bob, John, Stacey, and any number of people.

What I'm missing is a way to force concurrent logins to logout, if the same user. So if Bob tries to log in as Dave, then Dave (the original login) gets logged out.

I found a couple of examples that somewhat work around the issue, but they were a little dated, and were for MVC.

Comment: Depending on how you are checking security along the way within your app, you can kill all previously generated token etc. from working for a user so that only the latest login will work. However if you are not validating the user within the app (say at least at every page load and/or ajax request) then you will have more trouble with this. Could you share a little more about how your system is working, as Identity is highly customizable and everyone tends to create their own flavor.

Comment: @Kyle Right now, I'm using just the basic functionality. I started with the sort of template for ASP.NET that includes a Default page, all the Account pages (Login, Confirm, ManagePassword, etc.). I am only wanting to validate the user on each login, so in this scenario, upon login, it needs to check of that same user is already logged in, and if so, force a log out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by utilizing cookie authentication and an asynchronous method to update the security stamp.

Basically, the user's login information is stored in a cookie, which gets validated on every page load. When someone else logs in with the same username (or the same user logs in with a different browser), it updates the security stamp (causing invalidation for anyone currently logged in) and then proceeds to log the user in, using the updated stamp. On the login screen, my "Login" button's LogIn event is:

```
protected async void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then below in the body of the method, we have:

```
await signinManager.UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
await signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Username.Text, Password.Text, true, false);
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

This will ensure that every time a user logs in, their SecurityStamp is updated and stored in the database. And as long as the user goes back to the site in the same browser, then their login will be persisted. However, if any user comes behind them in a different browser and logs in using their same credentials, then the first account will be logged out.